# A different approach to proving a property of finite solvable groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, nilpotent-groups, solvable-groups

*Edit:* I'd be happy to hear any vague thoughts you might have, however far they may be from a complete solution!

I [asked this on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4763222/a-different-approach-to-proving-a-property-of-nilpotent-injectors-in-solvable-gr) a couple of days ago, but it didn't attract any attention so I decided to ask it here, since it is research-level mathematics.

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group. Let $J$ be a nilpotent subgroup of $G$ that contains $\mathbf{F}(G)$, and that is maximal in this regard (i.e. not properly contained in a larger nilpotent sugbroup). Then we say that $J$ is a Fischer subgroup.

I would like to show the following:

**Theorem:** If $M$ is subnormal in $G$, then $J\cap M$ is a Fischer subgroup of $M$.

It suffices to assume that $M$ is maximal normal in $G$, then apply induction to get to any subnormal subgroup. I have only managed to prove the theorem in the special case that $M$ *doesn't* contain $\mathbf{F}(G)$. Here's how it goes:

**PARTIAL PROOF:**

Let $F=\mathbf{F}(G)$, and suppose $F\not\subseteq M$. Then by maximality of $M$, $G=MF$. Since both $F$ and $M$ are normal in $G$, $[M,F]\subseteq F\cap M\subseteq\mathbf{F}(M)$.

Let $J$ be a Fischer subgroup of $G$. Let $K=J\cap M$. Dedekind's Lemma tells us that $J=FK$.

We want to show that $K$ is a Fischer subgroup of $M$.

$\mathbf{F}(M)=\mathbf{F}(G)\cap M\subseteq J\cap M=K$, so $K$ is contained in some Fischer subgroup $D$ of $M$. We aim to show that $D=K$.

Since $[M,F]\subseteq\mathbf{F}(M)\subseteq D$, we have that $[D,F]\subseteq D$, so $F$ normalizes $D$. Since $D$ and $F$ are both normal nilpotent subgroups of $\mathbf{N}_G(D)$, $DF$ is nilpotent.

Since $K\subseteq D$, we must have that $J=KF\subseteq DF$. By maximality of $J$, this forces $J=DF$, so $D\subseteq J\cap M=K$.

Hence, we have that $K=D$ as desired.

**END OF PARTIAL PROOF**

I feel that this is a promising approach, but I haven't been able to complete this proof. Does anyone know how to settle the remaining case of $F\subseteq M$? Notice that I haven't used the assumption that $G$ is solvable!

*Edit (11/9):* I can't use the fact that nilpotent injectors in a finite solvable group are unique up to conjugacy, because my eventual goal is to prove precisely this.

Comment: +1 for the excellent username.

Comment: Theorem 4.7 in Chapter VIII of Doerk-Hawkes,"Finite soluble groups". Or Theorem 7.10 in Wehrfritz, "Finite groups". In these references what you call a nilpotent injector is called a Fischer subgroup.

Comment: As @testaccount says, what you are trying to prove is a well known fact, proved in many texts, though there are differing definitions of "nilpotent injector" in the literature. The one you use is the same as a Fischer subgroup for solvable groups, and Fischer was first to define these, to prove that they are unique up to conjugacy, and prove the subnormality property you want.

Comment: I'm aware that this is a well-known fact, but it seems that existing proofs follow a different strategy to prove it. The half-proof that I described seems to be a promising strategy, and I'd like to know if it can be completed.

Comment: As you say, you haven't used solvability of $G$ so far. In particular, you haven't used that nilpotent injectors are unique up to conjugacy in solvable groups. Given this last fact, the case that $F(G) \leq M$ is easy, because $F(G) = F(M)$ in that case. A nilpotent injector of $M$ is therefore contained in some nilpotent  injector of $G$, and since the second is unique up to conjugacy in $G$ ( while $M$ already permutes the nilpotent injectors of $M$ transitively by conjugation), we see that every nilpotent injector $I$ of $G$ contains a nilpotent injector of $M$, which is just $I \cap M.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I'm very sorry, I should have included this in the original post: your argument works of course, but I would have liked to prove the uniqueness of Fischer subgroups up to conjugacy *given* that they are nilpotent injectors, and not the other way around. I have edited the main post.

Comment: I wanted to prove the conjugacy of Fischer subgroups via induction on $|G|$. If $J_1$ and $J_2$ are Fischer subgroups, and $M<G$ is a maximal normal subgroup that **doesn't** contain $F=\mathbf{F}(G)$, then $J_1=K_1F$ and $J_2=K_2F$, where $K_1$ and $K_2$ are Fischer subgroups of $M$ (this is what I have shown in my partial proof). Since $M<G$, I can apply the inductive hypothesis to see that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are conjugate in $M$. Since $F$ is normal in $G$, this means that $J_1$ and $J_2$ are conjugate, as desired...

Comment: (cont.) So I'm left with the case that *every* maximal normal subgroup of $G$ contains $F$.

Comment: Since, in a solvable group, we have $F(G/\Phi(G) = F(G)/\Phi(G)$ ( Gasch\"utz),  you can assume that $\Phi(G) = 1$. Then, in your situation, you can see that both $G/F(G_)$ and $F(G)$ are Abelian of squarefree exponent, and  $G$ is metabelian. I'm not sure that helps. I think the original line of reasoning is that for each prime $q$, a Sylow $q$-subgroup of a Fischer subgroup of $G$ is a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $C_{G}(O_{q^{\prime}}(F(G))$ . Given this, it also follows that when $F(G) = F(M)$ for some $M \lhd G,$ then a Fischer subgroup of $G$ meets $M$ in a Fischer subgroup of $M$.